# Where is kernel/user.c?

Tags: kernel, source-code

I am doing some changes on ubuntu linux source code. I used `find / -name user.c` command to locate `user.c` but failed. Where is it? My working environment is ubuntu14.04.

Comment: Try running the command `sudo updatedb && locate user.c`. That should search your PC for the file.

Comment: Where did you download the kernel sources to?

Comment: I do as you say, and I found there is no `user.c` in `/usr/src`, but some websites(Linux-cross-Reference)says there is a file `kernel/user.c`,could you please explain this for me? Thanks!

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install linux-source` and then re-run the commands RPi suggested.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I didn't download any source, I'm using ubuntu14.04, there are lots of source code in `/usr/src`,I chose `linux-headers-3.13.0-35` folder to do my changes in order not to do harm to my system once I failed. But where is that file? And could you please explain for my the right way to modify linux source code then compile and use it ?

Comment: @Seth I can't directly make use of source code ubuntu14.04 has offered? Could you please explain it for me? Thanks!

Comment: @BecomeBetter I can't remember exactly but I'm pretty sure you need to install that package to get the entire source, but someone could prove me wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't install the kernel source code, only kernel *headers* (usually ending in `.h`), which declare kernel interfaces exposed to user space.

You can get the kernel source code files (including those ending in `.c`) <s>by installing [linux-source](//apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/linux-source) [image: Install linux-source]</s> with

```
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

or by downloading the [code repository](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git?p=ubuntu/ubuntu-trusty.git;a=summary) (either through [Git](//apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/git) or with a click on the “snapshot“ link behind the newest revision in the shortlog). <s>If you choose to install the `linux-source` package, the source code files will reside below `/usr/src`.</s> If you download them manually, they'll be wherever you chose to clone/extract them.

For more information on how to compile your own kernel on Ubuntu refer too the [Ubuntu Wiki](//wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel). To make it very short, it basically comes down to

```sh
fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic
```

though I prefer the more versatile

```sh
make-kpkg --rootcmd fakeroot --initrd --jobs $(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) kernel-image kernel-headers
```

Edit: The stroked out text passages work as intended but aren't as useful if you aim to modify the kernel source and build your own kernel.

Comment: I also want to know after doing that, where the linux-source is located? Then I can modify the linux source?It would be better if you could show me some articles aiming for that:)

Comment: I added paragraphs about the location of the kernel sources and a link to a kernel build how-to.

Comment: when I ran command `make-kpkg --rootcmd fakeroot --initrd --jobs $(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) kernel-image kernel-headers`.It errs that `We do not seem to be in a top level linux kernel source directory
tree. Since we are trying to make a kernel package, that does not make
sense.  Please change directory to a top level linux kernel source
directory, and try again. (If I am wrong, and this is indeed a top
level linux kernel source directory, then I have gotten sadly out of
date with current kernels, and you should upgrade kernel-package)`,Where is the top level linux source ?

Comment: My working directory is `\usr\src\linux-source-3.13.0`,when I change it to `\usr\src`,it still errs like that.

Comment: I doubt you have write permission in `/usr/src` or its subdirectories. Building the kernel as `root` isn't such a good idea, because one should do as few things as possible as super-user (“With great power comes great responsibility”). It would probably be easier and cleaner to copy, clone, or download and extract the kernel source to a directory you own and build the kernel there.